QLPreviewController tool bar background color doesn't work if its a .rtf file
In my case I am using QLPreviewController .rtf file which have more pages. The background color is added with a UIVisualEffectView. I have tried disabling the same via navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false but it does not works
Here is my code a better solution is warm welcome
override var navigationController: UINavigationController? {
    super.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    super.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    super.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    if let toolbar = super.navigationController?.toolbar {
      toolbar.barStyle = .black
      toolbar.backgroundColor = .black
      toolbar.tintColor = .white
    }
    return super.navigationController
  }

